# Windows Batch Script for finding string within files with a specified date and copying to a new directory

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to do the following

```
FORFILES /S /M *.* /P <DIR> /D <MM/DD/YYYY>

FINDSTR /S /M /I <%CRITERIA%>

DO ECHO <FILE>

XCOPY /Y <FILE> <DIR>
```

### My original script is this

```
set /p search="Enter Search Criteria: "
set /p date="Enter Date (MM/DD/YYYY): "

if not exist "C:\%search%" mkdir C:\%search%

for /f %%a in ('findstr /s /m /i "%search%" "C:\log\*.txt"') do echo %%a & xcopy /y "%%a" "C:\%search%"

@pause
```

---

But it searches every single file on the server which can take a while, I'm hoping by reducing the list to the specified date I can focus the search.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, enter `RoboCopy /?` and read the output.

Comment: `%search%` is a file? If not, then add an extra `\ ` after `%search%`.

Comment: @Compo i wasnt able to use robocopy in this instance as i couldnt figure out how to initiate it in the DO and also reference the %%a. If possible i know robocopy would be better as i get a nice clean output. i was going to try xxcopy but it appears to have its limitations also

Comment: @double-beep %search% is referencing the users input for Criteria, this is any string really that could be within the files, example we have *.txt files and on the first line is a reference number AA-XXXXX, so if i type in that criteria it searches all the files that are related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **forfiles /D dd/mm/yyyy**  to search files never than date or use *minus sign* in front of date *to revert* it to older than date. It also takes +30 type days as date.

Comment: i was looking at forfiles but i could only see this as being useful if i somehow could narrow the file count for searching by nesting the findstr within a forfiles by date.